# Drag And Drop External Events FullCalendar React-Wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am not being able to drop external events on the calendar.
The calendar renders correctly, and the functions `select` and `eventClick` works as expected. 
I wanted to know now how to be able to drop external events in the calendar...
I've been reading [the fullcalendar.io documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing) and I'm not really able to do what I want.

The setting I am using is as follows:

```
<FullCalendar 
    id="calendario"
    header={{
        left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }}
    navLinks={true}
    nowIndicator={true}
    viewRender={(view, element) => {
        this.handleChangeView(view);
    }}
    selectable={true}
    editable={true}
    droppable={true}
    eventDrop={function(eventBj, date) {
        console.log('eventDrop function');
    }}
    drop={(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) => {
        console.log('drop function');
    }}
    select={(start, end, allDay) => {
        this.handleSelect(start, end, allDay);
    }}
    eventClick={(calEvent, jsEvent, view) => {
        this.handleClick(calEvent, jsEvent, view);
    }}
    events={events}
/>
```

I'm including jQuery-UI and the event triggers the `draggable`, I can hover with the external-event over the calendar.

**EDIT**

The drag effect is initiated in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle.

Note: I use a minifier in setting innerHTML, but I'll put it here without a minifier to understand it better.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.innerHTML = "$('.calendar-events').each(function() {
        $(this).data('event', {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()),
            stick: true
        });
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,
            revertDuration: 0
        })
    });";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

I have 0 errors and 0 warnings in console. And the drag effect happens like it should :/

**EDIT-2**

I'm currently using 2 classes to render the calendar:

1.

```
class Calendario extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.innerHTML =
      "$('.calendar-events').each(function(){$(this).data('event',{title:$.trim($(this).text()),stick:!0}),$(this).draggable({zIndex:999,revert:!0,revertDuration:0})});";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Grid container spacing={16} >
          <Grid item md={3}>
            Eventos
            <div className="calendar-events">
              <i className="fa fa-circle text-info" /> Consultas
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={9} style={{ minHeight: '500px' }}>
            <FullCalendarComponent />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Second

```
export class FullCalendarComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    view: 'agendaWeek',
    events: [
      {
        title: 'Static Event 1',
        start: '2018-11-20T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Static Event 2',
        start: '2018-11-21T16:00:00',
        end: '2018-11-21T18:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Static Event 3',
        start: '2018-11-20T11:00:00',
        end: '2018-11-20T13:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Static Event 4',
        start: '2018-11-22T14:00:00',
        end: '2018-11-22T16:00:00'
      }
    ]
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.events !== nextState.events) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  handleDrop = (eventObj, date) => {
    console.group('onDrop');
    console.log('date');
    console.dir(date);
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  handleSelect = (start, end, allDay) => {
    console.group('select');
    console.log('start');
    console.dir(start);
    console.dir('end');
    console.dir(end);
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  handleClick = (calEvent, jsEvent, view) => {
    console.group('click');
    console.log('calEvent');
    console.dir(calEvent);
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  handleChangeView = view => e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      view: view.name
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { events, view } = this.state;
    return (
      <FullCalendar 
        id="calendario"
        header={{
            left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        }}
        navLinks={true}
        nowIndicator={true}
        viewRender={(view, element) => {
            this.handleChangeView(view);
        }}
        selectable={true}
        editable={true}
        droppable={true}
        eventDrop={function(eventBj, date) {
            console.log('eventDrop function');
        }}
        drop={(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) => {
            console.log('drop function');
        }}
        select={(start, end, allDay) => {
            this.handleSelect(start, end, allDay);
        }}
        eventClick={(calEvent, jsEvent, view) => {
            this.handleClick(calEvent, jsEvent, view);
        }}
        events={events}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In my `index.html` file, I'm including scripts to `jquery.min.js` and `jquery-ui.min.js`

Comment: Have you seen the demo (https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/demos/external-dragging.html) and studied the source code of it?

Comment: Yes, I checked the code used in the documentation step by step and I followed these steps exactly. I have a version that works without using react, but now I wanted to make the transition. I start to think it might be from the package fullcalendar-reactwrapper...

Comment: ok thanks. So you say "I can hover with the external-event over the calendar"...what happens next? Any errors? Also you haven't actually shown us any of your draggable code so I can't really be sure if you've done it in a way that would be expected to work. I can't really see what difference react would be making here either.

Comment: I edited my question with the code that I think you asked

Comment: why are you building a script like that? What's wrong with just writing it as a normal script?? You're already in a JS function, so why not just keep writing JS, instead of making a string and then adding a tag to the page? Maybe I missed something but I can't understand what the advantage of that would be. And also where are your HTML draggable elements? I don't know if you've got anything with the "calendar-events" class to actually iterate over.

Comment: If I put my script like a normal script, when the external events render, the script wont "catch" none of the .calendar-events. I add the script like that, to "catch" the .calendar-events that already exist in the DOM. Do you suggest another workaround?

Comment: " the script wont "catch" none of the .calendar-events"...that's pretty odd...unless somehow you made this code run before those events were added to the DOM. maybe you need to check the order of execution in your code. Again, there's not enough info here for anyone to know for sure exactly what is happening

Comment: I added a second edit with all the code. I'm doing all the imports, I doesn't put the imports, so the post doesn't become really big.

Comment: Ok. And when you drop the event onto the calendar, do you get the `console.log('drop function');` log? Does it happen? P.S. why have you got `stick:!0` instead of `stick: true` in your JS?

Comment: No, it doesn't output 'drop function'... And no errors as well. That's because the minifier that I used :D

Comment: @RafaelVeloso Same problem i m facing please help me How to drag external event to calendar

Answer (score 0):

The callback `eventDrop` is only triggered for internal event drops.  You need to add the callback `eventReceive` for external event drops. Then you can at least tell if fullcalendar is detecting the drops.  I also have my fullcalendar inside a React wrapper, and after some trial and error, was able to make events draggable and it works perfectly!